# Disable Editing in rows if first Cell is empty for a datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am binding a DataTable to Datagrid. Number of columns and rows in datatable is determined at runtime. But number of rows displayed in datagrid is fixed to 36.

So if sometimes datatable have **<36 rows**, empty rows are displayed to maintain height of datagrid. Reason behind doing this is that I am printing the Grid containing datagrid and I dont want to mess up Height and Width of print template.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="TestPointsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding TestPointsTable,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" MouseRightButtonUp="DataGrid_MouseRightButtonUp"   
                                      CanUserAddRows="False" >
```

To disable first and last columns I did below style triggers :

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
          </Trigger>
          <DataTrigger Value="Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled"  Value="false" />
              <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
           </DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger Value="B or A" Binding="{Binding Path=Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled"  Value="false" />
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

Example : 
[image]

[image]

As shown in above images, numbers of columns are unknown.
First column and last column is always fixed in my case. i.e. `"Type"` and `"B or A"` respectively. I was able to set `IsEnabled = false` for these columns.

If there is something in first column, let user edit that row except first and last column. 
How do I set those empty rows' `IsEnabled` property to `false` ? Or just any workaround to prevent user from typing anything in those rows except not displaying those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do is to add a BeginningEdit event handler and cancel the edit if the row that the user is trying to edit is empty...

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding PartCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" BeginningEdit="dataGrid_BeginningEdit">

    private void dataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if((e.Row.Item as Part).Manufacturer == "XYZ")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what would be `Part` and `MAnufacturer` in my case ? DataType of rows in Datatable is unknown in my case.

Comment: Whatever the data row is behind the grid.  You didn't indicate what TestPointsTable was, so I simply used one of my tables.  If TestPointsTable is a DataTable, then e.Row.Item will be a DataRowView. So in this case will be (e.Row.Item as DataRowView).Row["Nominal"]